# jquery smooth scroll using visual studio code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to set up smooth scroll using jquery on my webpage.

I am working from this example here:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

When I copy and paste this into a js fiddle, it works fine. But for some reason it is not working on my website at all. As you can see I've linked my scripts.js file to my index.html, and i checked this in the console with a console.log message.

Here is my html:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Ubuntu:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Zane Mersky</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="heading">
                <div class="logo">
                    <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#philosophy">My Philosophy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">My Classroom</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Professional Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="/assets/IMG_6543.JPG" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="left-intro"></div>

            <div class="right-intro">
                <div class="quote">
                    <h3>"Childhood is not a race to see how quickly a child can read, write and count. It is a small window of time to learn and develop at the pace that is right for each individual child. <br class="break"> Earlier is not better."</h3>
                    <h3 class="author">-Magda Gerber</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section class="philosophy">
                <h1 id="philosophy">My Philosophy</h1>
                <div class="paragraph wrapper">

                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="about">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </section>          
    </main>      
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the jquery I am using:

```
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: would you please add the structure of your project?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you put the link to your JS file in the head. Put it at the bottom of the body and it will work.

Always put your links to JS files before the closing tag of the body.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you probably have added script in the head and your document loads after the script is executed in the head. To get your script working you should either add it at the bottom of the body or add a script to check if document is ready just like i have done in the code snippet here:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b071c752c

`$("document").ready(...` loads the script after the document has loaded.